# Run function on active anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-events

I'm new to jQuery and want to highlight div's if the div's anchor id is set.

I currently have this construct which only works on page load with an valid anchor attached.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divpost = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if($.isNumeric(divpost)){
        $('#reply_' + divpost).css('background-color', '#EDA2FF');
    }
});
```

This works only on page load with a set anchor. How can I make this more dynamic so the script executes whenever the anchor changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can hook into the [`hashchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) so you can do this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var divpost = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if($.isNumeric(divpost)){
        $('#reply_' + divpost).css('background-color', '#EDA2FF');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not find this while searching for anchors.

Comment: Note you'll also want to add logic to return the no-longer-matching div to the default colour.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a function and call it with every update.

```
function updateAnchors() {
    var divpost = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if($.isNumeric(divpost)){
        $('#reply_' + divpost).css('background-color', '#EDA2FF');
    }
}
```

Then call `updateAnchors()` when more anchors are loaded.

Comment: So I would call that via onClick if I understand that right? Or is there a way to call it if the anchor changes?

Comment: exactly, using `$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  //.. work ..
});` 
or like @miken32 did without splitting the function and the hash change :)